# Merging multiple maps in Java 8

Tags: java, dictionary, collections, java-8

Java 8 here. I have the following classes:

```
public interface Animal {
  ...
}

public class Dog implements Animal {
  ...
}

public class Cat implements Animal {
  ...
}

public class Elephant implements Animal {
  ...
}
```

I have to implement the following method:

```
void doSomething(Map<String,Dog> dogs, Map<String,Cat> cats, Map<String,Elephant> elephants) {
  // TODO:
  // * Merge all dogs, cats & elephants together into the same Map<String,Animal>,
  //     but...
  // * Do so generically (without having to create, say, a HashMap instance, etc.)
}
```

In my `doSomething(...)` method, I need to merge all the map arguments into the same `Map<String,Animal>` map, **but** I'd really prefer to do so without **my code** having to instantiate a specific map implementation (such as `HashMap`, etc.).

Meaning, I *know* I could do this:

```
void doSomething(Map<String,Dog> dogs, Map<String,Cat> cats, Map<String,Elephant> elephants) {
  Map<String,Animal> animals = new HashMap<>();
  for(String dog : dogs.keySet()) {
    animals.put(dog, dogs.get(dog));
  }
  for(String cat : cats.keySet()) {
    animals.put(cat, cats.get(cat));
  }
  for(String elephant : elephants.keySet()) {
    animals.put(elephant, elephants.get(elephant));
  }

  // Now animals has all the argument maps merged into it, but is specifically
  // a HashMap...
}
```

I'm even fine using some utility if it exists, like maybe a `Collections.merge(dogs, cats, elephants)`, etc. Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid instantiating a new map?

Comment: Thanks @shmosel but not looking for an XY Answer here.

Comment: I'm actually trying to understand the requirement. Is it not to create a new object? Not to use a particular implementation? To use the same implementation as the arguments? To support various implementations? It's not very clear what your goal is. Note that all the answers provided so far do, in fact, instantiate a new map.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One way to do it would be to create a stream of sets of entries and then flatmap it to have a stream of entries and collect those into a map.

```
Map<String,Animal> animals = 
    Stream.of(dogs.entrySet(), cats.entrySet(), elephants.entrySet())
          .flatMap(Set::stream)
          .collect(toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));

//Stream.of(dogs, cats, elephants).flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream()) could also be an option
```

Also not a one-liner and without streams using `Map#putAll`:

```
Map<String,Animal> animals = new HashMap<>(dogs);
animals.putAll(cats);
animals.putAll(elephants);
```

Comment: Thanks @Alexis C (+1) but where is your `toMap(...)` static method coming from?

Comment: @smeeb `java.util.stream.Collectors`

Comment: I would make a small improvement: `Stream.of(dogs, cats, elephants).map(Map::entrySet)`

Comment: @shmosel But then you'll need to flatmap the stream i.e `Stream.of(dogs, cats, elephants).map(Map::entrySet).flatMap(Set::stream)`. In this case, I prefer to write `Stream.of(dogs, cats, elephants).flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream())` directly, but matter of taste I guess.

Comment: @smeeb From the [`Collectors` class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html). If you want to have a specific map implementation, you can use this [overloaded method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-java.util.function.Supplier-).

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish the task at hand with the use of [**`Stream.Concat`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#concat-java.util.stream.Stream-java.util.stream.Stream-):

```
Map<String,Animal> animals = Stream.concat(Stream.concat(dogs.entrySet().stream(), cats.entrySet().stream()), elephants.entrySet().stream())
                                   .collect(Collectors.toMap
                                    (
                                       Map.Entry::getKey,
                                       Map.Entry::getValue
                                    )
                              );
```

You'll need to be cautious here because when merging and there are duplicate keys then an exception will be raised as expected.

Comment: Thanks @Aomine (+1) - but your code yields the following error: "*Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context*"...any ideas?

Comment: that's most likely because you're calling the method `doSomething` inside a static context. that's nothing to do with the solution at hand. 2 ways to solve it.  1 is to instantiate an object of the containing type and then call the `doSomething` from the new instance or make the `doSomething` method static.

Comment: Ok, however `doSomething(...)` is **not** a static method. I'll start playing around with it a little.

Comment: Yeah I'm following you, still something else is going on. This is a compiler (not runtime) error, and this is a library I'm building (so I don't have any other place in the code where `doSomething(...)` is explicitly called).

Answer (score 1):

The best way IMO is as in [Alexis C.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47117245/1876620), with `Map.putAll`:

```
Map<String, Animal> animals = new HashMap<>(dogs);
animals.putAll(cats);
animals.putAll(elephants);
```

A variant on this one:

```
Map<String, Animal> animals = new HashMap<>(dogs);
cats.forEach(animals::put);
elephants.forEach(animals::put);
```

Comment: Thanks @Federico but that still requires me to instantiate `animals` as a  `HashMap`. It sounds like their are other (stream-based) ways to avoid this so I'm more interested in those.

Comment: @smeeb It's undocumented, but `toMap()` also produces a `HashMap`.